# What distribution has exactly three parameters for mean, variance, and skewness?

Tags: distributions, skewness, gamlss, skew-normal-distribution

Common distributions usually fix their skewness. Beta distribution has two parameters to determine all of the mean, variance, and skewness.

Student-T's skewness can change by some definitions but it does not have a dedicated parameter.

What distribution has exactly three parameters for mean, variance, and skewness?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpGammaDistribution.html

Comment: Infinitely many answers are possible.  Some appear at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinitely many answers are possible, some links in comments. One family is the [skew-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), but it only admits limited degrees of skewness. The same ideas used to construct the skew-normal family from the normal family can be used for other families!

For empirical modeling with skewness have a look at the [gamlss](https://www.gamlss.com/) system, which admits many families.